# JavaScript/HTML variable trouble

Tags: javascript, variables, var

This is my code:

```
<HTML>
    <HEADER>
        <TITLE>Page</TITLE>
    </HEADER>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var asdf=Math.floor(Math.random()*80000000)
</SCRIPT>
<FORM> 
<input type=button 
value="button"
onClick="self.location='http://www.roblox.com/place-place?id=$_GET["var asdf"]'">
</FORM>
    <BODY>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

---

How do i fix it so the link is random, but also works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try this

<HTML>
<HEADER>
 <TITLE>Page</TITLE>
</HEADER>
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function my_func()
{
var asdf= Math.floor(Math.random()*80000000);
window.open("http://www.roblox.com/place-place?id="+asdf);
}

</SCRIPT>
<FORM> 
<input type=button value="button" onClick="my_func()">
 </FORM>
<BODY>
</BODY>
 </HTML>

you can also use window.location instead of window.open.
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the value of `onclick` to:

```
"var asdf=Math.floor(Math.random()*80000000); window.location='http://www.roblox.com/place-place?id='+asdf"
```

This will randomize the ID on every click of the link

Answer (score 0):

Use a function,

```
function redirect(){
self.location='http://www.roblox.com/place-place?id='+asdf;
}
```

an call the function onclick of input tag